# Cannot create directory with sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

## Question

Why sudo cannot create a directory with the error?

```
USER=ansible

AUTH_KEY_DIR="$(sudo -i -u ${USER} pwd)/.ssh"
AUTH_KEY_FILE="${AUTH_KEY_DIR}/.ssh/authorized_keys"

# ERROR >-bash: mkdir /home/ansible/.ssh: No such file or directory
sudo -i -u ${USER} "mkdir ${AUTH_KEY_DIR}"   # <----- Error is caused here. 
sudo -i -u ${USER} "touch ${AUTH_KEY_FILE}"
```

### Solution

```
sudo -i -u ${USER} /bin/bash -c "mkdir ${AUTH_KEY_DIR}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much qouting. The `sudo` command does not re-tokenize the commands:

```
sudo -i -u ${USER} mkdir "${AUTH_KEY_DIR}"
```

It cannot create directory the same way running:

```
"mkdir ${AUTH_KEY_DIR}"
```

will try to find a executable named `mkdir ${AUTH_KEY_DIR}` and run it. You want to run `mkdir` with an argument `${AUTH_KEY_DIR}`.